# Are there any options for distributing a test build to more than 100 testers?

Tags: ios, xcode

We would like to distribute our app internally within the company for dogfood testing, however ad-hoc distribution of test builds is limited to 100 devices.
Is there any way of distributing it beyond 100?

The app will eventually be released to the App Store, but while under development/testing could the company additionally register for an enterprise developer account and distribute the dogfood builds as an enterprise app?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option will be, register your self to enterprise program not developer program. That way you can distribute ad-hoc build to everyone in your company

Link: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Answer (score 0):

You are correct the only official way you could do this through Apple provisioning would be to release it as an Enterprise Ad-Hoc app, as development testing your limited to 100 devices.
short of paying another $99 and using another 100 devices...